# Правильно ли говорить "общее между"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить "общее между", например, в:

> Что **между** ними **общего**?

По ощущениям, *между* наоборот разделяет два объекта, у которых мы ищем *общее,* поэтому всегда хочется заменить, например, на такое:

> Что **у** них **общего**?

А *между* использовать в:

> Какая **между** ними **разница**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать сочетание ‟между ними общего” можно, так как люди массово говорили и говорят так, согласно тому же Нац. корпусу.
Ну, однако ж, что может быть между ними общего? [Ф. М. Достоевский. Преступление и наказание (1866)]
И что же, по-вашему, тогда между ними общего?» [Андрей Геласимов. Рахиль // «Октябрь», 2003]

Устоявшиеся сочетания так не работают, что если кому-то не нравится буквальное значение, которое получается в результате сочетания, то так нельзя говорить.